# How can I assign multiple values to an Object[]?

Tags: java

I am using this piece of code to insert into hashmap.

I have assigned the multiple values to the `Object[]`, but when I run the program I am getting these errors.

How can I solve this error:

```
<identifier> expected
illegal start of type
 ';' expected
```

Code:

```
public final static Object[] longValues = {"10", "iosl-proi", "10.10.10.10.10.","5","O"},{"11", "pree-lee1", "12.1.2.","4","O"},{"13", "trtg-lv1t", "4.6.1.","3","O"};
```

Comment: It is illegal assignment to an array. You should delete after second curly braces.

Comment: use 2 dimansional array as Object[][] values = { {value, value}, {value, value}};

Comment: Why are you not creating a class that correctly holds your data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You appear to be creating a multi-dimensional array. Perhaps this is what you want?

```
public final static Object[][] longValues = {
    {"10", "iosl-proi", "10.10.10.10.10.","5","O"},
    {"11", "pree-lee1", "12.1.2.","4","O"},
    {"13", "trtg-lv1t", "4.6.1.","3","O"}
};
```

Although, given the pattern in your object values, perhaps you actually want to create a class to store these values?

Comment: @JunedAhsan It is a two-dimensional object array. It compiles without error.

Comment: @JunedAhsan: sure it will, what compiler error do you expect?

Comment: @DuncanJones +1 given as well :-)

Answer (score 1):

Add another set of `{ }` around and use `[][]` to denote an Array of Array.

```
public final static Object[][] longValues =
             {{"10", "iosl-proi", "10.10.10.10.10.","5","O"},
              {"11", "pree-lee1", "12.1.2.","4","O"},
              {"13", "trtg-lv1t", "4.6.1.","3","O"}};
```

Comment: What kind of array it is? It will not compile

Comment: Ah, got it! Forgot the `[]`. Thanks Ashish :)

Comment: @RaviThapliyal Ok as you have corrected the mistake, vote taken back ;-)

Comment: @JunedAhsan Thanks appreciate it. Was just too focussed on the braces. My bad though.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are assigning multidimensional array to single dimensional array.You need to create multidimensional array as below.

```
public final static Object[][] longValues =
            { {"10", "iosl-proi", "10.10.10.10.10.","5","O"},
              {"11", "pree-lee1", "12.1.2.","4","O"},
              {"13", "trtg-lv1t", "4.6.1.","3","O"}  };
```